# Python: group by with sum special columns and keep the initial rows too

Tags: pandas, group-by, sum, apply, concatenation

I have a `df`:

```
ID  Car       Jan17     Jun18  Dec18  Apr19                            
0   Nissan     0.0       1.7    3.7    0.0       
1   Porsche    10.0      0.0    2.8    3.5       
2   Golf       0.0       1.7    3.0    2.0   
3   Tiguan     1.0       0.0    3.0    5.2         
4   Touareg    0.0       0.0    3.0    4.2    
5   Mercedes   0.0       0.0    0.0    7.2    
6   Passat     0.0       3.0    0.0    0.0
```

I would like to change the values for row #6: `Passat` value in `Car` column by add the values from row#2 & row#3 & row#4 `(Golf, Tiguan, Touareg)` in the `Car` column) and also keep the values of row#2 & row#3 & row#4 as initial.
Because `Passat` includes `Golf, Touareg, Tiguan` and due to it I need to add the values of `Golf, Touareg, Tiguan`rows to `Passat` row.

I tried to do it the following code: 
`car_list = ['Golf', 'Tiguan', 'Touareg']`

```
for car in car_list:
  df['Car'][df['Car']==car]='Passat'
```

and after I used `groupby` by `Car` and `sum()` function:

`df1 = df.groupby(['Car'])['Jan17', 'Jun18', 'Dec18', 'Apr19'].sum().reset_index()`

In result, `df1` doesn't have initial `(Golf, Tiguan, Touareg)` rows. So, this way is wrong.

Expected result is `df1`:

```
ID  Car       Jan17     Jun18  Dec18  Apr19                            
0   Nissan     0.0       1.7    3.7    0.0       
1   Porsche    10.0      0.0    2.8    3.5       
2   Golf       0.0       1.7    3.0    2.0   
3   Tiguan     1.0       0.0    3.0    5.2         
4   Touareg    0.0       0.0    3.0    4.2    
5   Mercedes   0.0       0.0    0.0    7.2       
6   Passat     1.0       4.7    9.0    11.4
```

I'd appreciate for any idea. Thanks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is in view of function:

```
car_list = ['Golf', 'Tiguan', 'Touareg', 'Passat']

 def updateCarInfoBySum(df, car_list, name, id):
      req = df[df['Car'].isin(car_list)]
      req.set_index(['Car', 'ID], inplace=True)
      req.loc[('new_value', '000'), :] = req.sum(axis=0)
      req.reset_index(inplace=True)
      req = req[req.Car != name]
      req['Car'][req['Car'] == 'new_value'] = name
      req['ID'][req['ID'] == '000'] = id
      req.set_index(['Car', 'ID], inplace=True)
      df_final = df.copy()
      df_final.set_index(['Car', 'ID], inplace=True)
      df_final.update(req)
      return df_final
```

Answer (score 1):

First we use `.isin` to get the correct `Cars`, then we use `.filter` to get the correct value columns, finally we `sum` the values and put them in our variable `sums`.

Then we select the `Passat` row and add the values to that row:

```
sums = df[df['Car'].isin(car_list)].filter(regex='\w{3}\d{2}').sum()

df.loc[df['Car'].eq('Passat'), 'Jan17':] += sums
```

**Output**

```
   ID       Car  Jan17  Jun18  Dec18  Apr19
0   0    Nissan    0.0    1.7    3.7    0.0
1   1   Porsche   10.0    0.0    2.8    3.5
2   2      Golf    0.0    1.7    3.0    2.0
3   3    Tiguan    1.0    0.0    3.0    5.2
4   4   Touareg    0.0    0.0    3.0    4.2
5   5  Mercedes    0.0    0.0    0.0    7.2
6   6    Passat    1.0    4.7    9.0   11.4
```

Comment: thank you for idea. But, there is an issue, when i changed the list of ```car_list``` to ```car_list = ['Porsche']``` and used ```sums = df[df['Car'].isin(car_list)].filter(regex='\w{3}\d{2}').sum()```, ```df.loc[df['Car'].eq('Mercedes'), 'Jan17':] += sums```. In Result i Receved ```NaN``` in rows for ```Mercedes```. I don't understand why it happened.

Comment: I just tried it, and it worked. Try to restart your kernel, or load your dataset in again, so you can start the code all over again. @Cindy

Comment: I don't know why, but ```sums = df[df['Car'].isin(car_list)].filter(regex='\w{3}\d{2}').sum()``` returns empty pd.series. Due to it I tried to do it in longer way. Anyway thanks a lot for short solution.